# Symfony 4 says Entity not found but entity exists and work in different controller

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I've an Entity called `File` in `src/Entity` directory.
When I try to use it in a controller called `FileViewController` I get an error saying `Entity App\Entity\File does not exists` But when I use the same Entity in `FileController` it works perfectly!
The `FileViewController` reads data from database and the `FileController` store/delete/edit the data 
Code inside `FileViewController`

```
<?php
namespace ...
...
...
use App\Entity\File as uFile; //uFile to prevent possible collision

/**
* @Route("/view/{slug}", name="view")
*/

function view1($slug, Request $request, SessionInterface $session) {
    ...
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(uFile::class); //error comes from here
    $hasFile = $em->findOneBy(['slug'=>$slug]);
    ... 
}
```

The `FileController` has exactly the same lines as  those lines above but populates no error!
Here is a screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/58S5R.jpg
Here I've no clue anymore :(

Comment: The error in your screenshot shows exactly what you're doing wrong. You try to call `->getManager()` which is incorrect method call in your case. Replace it with `->getRepository()` because I am willing to bet this is what you want to do.

Comment: Also, if I remember correctly, it's not recommended to use `getDoctrine()->getRepository`. You should either Inject your Repository or inject a Service that use the Repository.